# How can I create a multi table in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables. In one there is a column with the price of the product and I need to combine it with the column *nazwa_kategorii* in the second, and write out the sum of all services.

```
Nazwa usługi             Cena usługi ID Kategorii
Abonament za Internet    40.00       1
Bezpieczny Internet      9.90        3
Telewizja Pakiet pełny   80.00       2
GigaNagrywarka           15.00       2
Rabat za Internet       -20.00       1





ID Kategorii     Nazwa Kategorii   Kolejność sortowania
1                Internet          1
2                Telewizja         3
3                Usługi Dodatkowe  2
```

At the end it should give this result:

```
Kategoria podsumowania Kwota
Internet               20.00
Usługi Dodatkowe       9.90
Telewizja              95.00
```

I can't figure out how to complete the query so that it writes me all the columns, not just one. Here is an example:

```
select Nazwa_kategorii,sum(Cena_uslugi ) as kwota
from (Kategorii left join Uslugi on Kategorii.id_kategorii = Uslugi.id_kategorii)
where (Uslugi.id_kategorii =1 );
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: You forgot to add `group by`. I.e., `where (Uslugi.id_kategorii =1 );` --> `where (Uslugi.id_kategorii =1 ) group by Nazwa_kategorii;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select nazwa_kategorii, sum(cena_uslugi) kwota
from kategorie k
join uslugi u on k.id_kat = u.id_kat
group by nazwa_kategorii
```

| nazwa_kategorii | kwota |
| --- | --- |
| Telewizja | 95.00 |
| Usługi dodatkowe | 9.90 |
| Internet | 20.00 |

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=35d64442a58ed811cbbffddcf60245f2